# Errors Passing Template Arguments with Template Functions

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments, member

I'm having trouble using template member functions and template variables. The goal is to create an template for an interface which can be inherited and linked to one or more services initialized at runtime.  This interface would also pass data to these specialized services (e.g. MyService).  For a  simpler example, with this code:

```
#include <string>

class Interface
{
public:
    template <class T> bool init(T *_Service) {AttachService(*_Service);}  //This function does other stuff too.
    template <typename T> void AttachService(T _Service) { m_AttachedService<T> = *_Service; }
    template <typename T> T AttachedService() { return m_AttachedService; }
protected:
    template<typename T> static T m_AttachedService;

    class InterfaceListener
    {
        void Received()
        {
            int a = 1;
            std::string b = "hello";
            AttachedService().setA(a);
            m_AttachedService.setB(b);
        };
    };
};

class Service
{
    Service();
    ~Service();
    virtual void init() = 0;
};

class MyService : public Service, public Interface
{
    MyService();
    ~MyService();
    private:
        int A;
        std::string B;
    protected:
        Interface x;
    public:
        void init() { x.init(this);}
        void setA(int a) { A = a; }
        void setB(std::string b) { B = b; }
};

int main();
{
    MyService myserv;
    myserv.init();
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
C2672: 'Interface::AttachedService': no matching overloaded function found
C2783:  'T Interface::AttachedService(void)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
C2228:  left of '.setA' must have class/struct/union
C3245:  'Interface::m_AttachedService': use of a variable template requires template argument list
```

Any help understanding proper usage of templates would be appreciated!

Comment: `{ return m_AttachedService; }` -> `{ return m_AttachedService<T>; }`

Comment: After making that change, I get 4 other errors tied to the same things (e.g. argments for m_AttachedService variable template missing, b is not a type name, etc.)

Comment: You've got quite a few more problems. It does not make sense to me to formulate an answer since it's not clear to me what you are trying to do. By suggestion will be to create a [mcve] on your computer until you are able to figure out how to resolve the build errors.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought I was doing.  I omitted other code that calls Receive() for simplicity.  As far as what I'm trying to do, based on what I described above the goal would be to further expand the code such that this template interface could be used to pass data to any specialized service defined which could then act on that data.  For example, I could add a doSomething() method to MyService that Receive() could call when new data was available which the service would act on.

Comment: Still looking for any help and guidance on how to address these compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a minimal program that builds and runs without doing anything useful.

```
#include <string>

class Interface
{
};

class Service
{
   protected:
      Service() {}
      ~Service() {}
      virtual void init() = 0;
};

class MyService : public Service, public Interface
{
   private:
      int A;
      std::string B;
   protected:
      Interface x;
   public:
      MyService() {}
      ~MyService() {}
      void init() {}
      void setA(int a) { A = a; }
      void setB(std::string b) { B = b; }
};

int main()
{
   MyService myserv;
   myserv.init();
}
```

You'll notice that there are few changes from your posted code to get to that baseline.

1. `Interface` is empty.
2. The member functions of `Service` are in `public` section. The default constructor and the destructor of `Service` have an empty implementation.
3. The default constructor and the destructor of `MyService` are in the `public` section of the class and they have empty implementations.
4. `MyService::init()` has an empty implementation.

---

Now we can start adding more code.

I changed `MyService::init()` to:

```
  void init() { x.init(this); }
```

With no other changes, I got the following compiler error.

```
socc.cc: In member function ‘virtual void MyService::init()’:
socc.cc:25:23: error: ‘class Interface’ has no member named ‘init’
       void init() { x.init(this);}
```

Now, `Interface` needs to be updated with an `init` function.

I added a dummy implementation to move the process forward.

```
class Interface
{
   public:
      template <class T> bool init(T *_Service) { return true; }
};
```

Time to add something useful to `Interface::init()`. Changing it to

```
template <class T> bool init(T *_Service)
{
   AttachService(*_Service); 
   return true; 
}
```

produces the following compiler error, which is not surprising.

```
socc.cc: In instantiation of ‘bool Interface::init(T*) [with T = MyService]’:
socc.cc:31:32:   required from here
socc.cc:8:23: error: ‘AttachService’ was not declared in this scope
          AttachService(*_Service);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Time to add `AttachService`. Changing `Interface` to (closing matching what you have)

```
class Interface
{
   public:
      template <class T> bool init(T *_Service)
      {
         AttachService(*_Service); 
         return true; 
      }

      template <typename T> void AttachService(T _Service)
      {
         m_AttachedService<T> = *_Service;
      }

   protected:
      template<typename T> static T m_AttachedService;
};
```

produces the following compiler error.

```
socc.cc: In instantiation of ‘void Interface::AttachService(T) [with T = MyService]’:
socc.cc:8:10:   required from ‘bool Interface::init(T*) [with T = MyService]’
socc.cc:39:32:   required from here
socc.cc:14:33: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘MyService’)
          m_AttachedService<T> = *_Service;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
```

That makes sense. In `AttachServie`, `_Service` is not a pointer.

Changing `Inteface::AttachService` to:

```
  template <typename T> void AttachService(T _Service)
  {
     m_AttachedService<T> = _Service;
  }
```

makes the compiler error go away but there is a linker error.

```
:socc.cc:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN9Interface17m_AttachedServiceI9MyServiceEE[.refptr._ZN9Interface17m_AttachedServiceI9MyServiceEE]+0x0): undefined reference to `Interface::m_AttachedService<MyService>'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That makes sense since we have not defined the `static` member variable.

Adding the following line

```
template<typename T> T Interface::m_AttachedService;
```

right after definition of `Interface` takes care of the linker error.

The following is the next version of the complete program that builds successfully and runs even though it still doesn't do anything useful.

```
#include <string>

class Interface
{
   public:
      template <class T> bool init(T *_Service)
      {
         AttachService(*_Service); 
         return true; 
      }

      template <typename T> void AttachService(T _Service)
      {
         m_AttachedService<T> = _Service;
      }

   protected:
      template<typename T> static T m_AttachedService;
};

template<typename T> T Interface::m_AttachedService;

class Service
{
   protected:
      Service() {}
      ~Service() {}
      virtual void init() = 0;
};

class MyService : public Service, public Interface
{
   private:
      int A;
      std::string B;
   protected:
      Interface x;
   public:
      MyService() {}
      ~MyService() {}
      void init() { x.init(this); }
      void setA(int a) { A = a; }
      void setB(std::string b) { B = b; }
};

int main()
{
   MyService myserv;
   myserv.init();
}
```

---

Time to add your version of the `AttachedService` to `Interface`

```
template <typename T> T AttachedService() { return m_AttachedService; }
```

That produces the following compiler error.

```
socc.cc: In member function ‘T Interface::AttachedService()’:
socc.cc:17:73: error: missing template arguments before ‘;’ token
     template <typename T> T AttachedService() { return m_AttachedService; }
```

That makes sense since `m_AttachedService` is not a member variable but a member variable template.

Changing that to

```
template <typename T> T AttachedService() { return m_AttachedService<T>; }
```

removes that error.

---

Now the final piece in `Interface`. The nested class `InterfaceListener` that you have posted does sound right. You have

```
  class InterfaceListener
  {
     void Received()
     {
        int a = 1;
        std::string b = "hello";
        AttachedService().setA(a);
        m_AttachedService.setB(b);
     };
  };
```

Problems in that class:

1. `AttachedService()` is not right since it a member function template. You have to provide a template parameter to use it.
2. Also, `AttachedService()` is not a `static` member function. You need an instance of `Interface` to make that call.
3. `m_AttachedService` is not a member variable. It is a member variable template.  You have to provide a template parameter to use it.
4. The functions `setA()` and `setB()` are valid only if the template parameter is `MyService`. It does not make sense to have code in that function that is specific to a type.

---

I'll leave it for you to ponder over how you intend to use `InterfaceListener` and define its functions appropriately. Until then the following program builds and runs for me.

```
#include <string>

class Interface
{
   public:
      template <class T> bool init(T *_Service)
      {
         AttachService(*_Service); 
         return true; 
      }

      template <typename T> void AttachService(T _Service)
      {
         m_AttachedService<T> = _Service;
      }

      template <typename T> T AttachedService() { return m_AttachedService<T>; }

   protected:
      template<typename T> static T m_AttachedService;

};

template<typename T> T Interface::m_AttachedService;

class Service
{
   protected:
      Service() {}
      ~Service() {}
      virtual void init() = 0;
};

class MyService : public Service, public Interface
{
   private:
      int A;
      std::string B;
   protected:
      Interface x;
   public:
      MyService() {}
      ~MyService() {}
      void init() { x.init(this); }
      void setA(int a) { A = a; }
      void setB(std::string b) { B = b; }
};

int main()
{
   MyService myserv;
   myserv.init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough breakdown.  Unfortunately, the part that I'm struggling with is the critical part you omitted at the end which is the nested InterfaceListener class.  I've successfully run this interface code by specializing it for each service that I wish to integrate.  It's attempting to reformat this top level interface and listener classes where I am running into issues, and I probably still don't grasp proper use of templates.  To clarify a bit more, this nested listener will execute Received() when new data is received, but this data is only accessible within this method so...

Comment: ..within this method I must assess the data and if I want the service (e.g. MyService) to act on it I currently modify and store it in the instance of m_AttachedService. (At runtime, the objective is to initiate the service with its instance of the interface and listener).  So while both instances will be instantiated at runtime, I am attempting to reference template variables that it sounds I must provide an instance of.  How do I do that?  Within main I specify the service instance which in turn sets the interface instance and m_AttachedService instance that I want to reference from there.

Comment: So as I continue to research and learn, I think what I'm trying to achieve is Dependency Injection using templates.  (There is also the nested class nuance that I am constrained too though).  As alluded to before, this is all in an effort to share data between classes, and I am constrained somewhat on the interface side.

Comment: There are three components to the dependency injection pattern. A client, one or more services, and the service injectors. I am not seeing those in your posted code.

Comment: That's because I didn't have it in mind when I started.  I need Receive() to be able to add data (e.g. tasks) to MyService() and then have this linked service act on it.  Since Receive() quickly ends, I need a way for this data to persist.  It will basically perform a consistent set of operations for any derived class type of Service() so I want to have 1 Interface class support any derived service.  This is why I looked at template functions.  Perhaps I could use shared_ptrs or pass a derived ref for a base parameter(?), but in each case I'm running into issues accessing member functions.